# Cannot Uninstall or Repair Visual Studio 2010..I get "operation cannot be completed" error!

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, uninstallation

I get "operation cannot be completed" error when i tried repair or uninstall visual studio  2010 RC1...I tried restarting my computer and doing it couple of times...but it just does not let me do an repair or an uninstall and it completes half way and give me "operation cannot be completed" and just hangs...after that and does nothing anyone has any ideas? I even tried installing other components manually but those dont work either...please help me out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to reinstall RC1 and then uninstall :-)

Update:

Things to consider (use at your own risk!)

Read posts in this thread
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxsetup/thread/a5d827d7-05b4-41b9-9565-e9e4abb12e66/

Use the .NET framework cleanup tool
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160301085724/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx)

Comment: I tried renistall but it only gives me an option to repair and repair does not work..